# Как обрезать строку [from:to] в C++ для char[]?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, память, char

Никак не могу найти возможность обрезать строку char[], начиная с элемента с индексом **k**, до элемента с индексом **g**. В *Python* это можно сделать с помощью **string[from:to]**, можно ли что-то подобное сделать в *C++*?

Вот код, которым я пытался это сделать, но он ведет себя непредсказуемо странно при разных значениях переменной **str**:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char A[7];
    char B[8];
    char C[4];
    char str[] = "AAAAABBBBCCC";

    strncpy(A, str, 5);
    strncpy(B, str+5, 4);
    strncpy(C, str+5+4, 3);
    std::cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Где на выходе я получаю странное:
`AAAAA BBBB CCCРBBBB`

**[UPD]** Решение, к которому я пришел:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void substr(char* dest, char* source, int from, int length){
    strncpy(dest, source+from, length);
    dest[length] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    char A[7];
    char B[8];
    char C[4];
    char str[] = "AAAAABBBBCCC";

    substr(A, str, 0,  5);
    substr(B, str, 6, 4);
    substr(C, str, 6+4, 3);
    std::cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в консоль: `AAAAA BBBB CCC`

Comment: Вам стоит разобраться хотя бы с основами. "char[]" вовсе не строка, а массив char, массивы char в общем случае нельзя индексировать по буквам, чтобы массив char подпадал под определение C-string после значащих символов должен располагаться завершающий ноль и т.д. Ну а если используете C++, то можно использовать класс std::string в котором уже есть функциональность наподобии `string[from:to]`. А еще лучше какой-нибудь сторонний класс для работы со стоками, так как из коробки С++ мало что может предложить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Руками, например:

```
char* slice(char*s, int from, int to)
{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = from; i <= to; ++i)
        s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = 0;
    return s;
};
```

Или с помощью `memmove` -

```
char* slice(char*s, int from, int to)
{
    memmove(s,s+from, to-from+1);
    s[to-from+1] = 0;
    return s;
};
```

Проверки, что `from`, `to` в пределах строки и что `from < to` - допишите сами.

Можно - если это позволяет ваша задача - просто

```
char* slice(char*s, int from, int to)
{
    s[to+1] = 0;
    return s+from;
};
```

Ну, т.е. обрезать строку и обращаться по новому адресу :)

Comment: Думал о таком варианте решения [обход циклом], но мне нужно что-то более оптимизированное, потому что подобный "срез" строк будет происходить достаточно часто в проекте.

Comment: Оптимизируйте сам принцип. Например, см. последний вариант в ответе. Если хотите куда-то копировать - быстрее не будет...